# Is it possible to draw an information flow between two states

Tags: uml

In sparx Architect, it is possible to model between two states in a state machine diagram, as shown in the diagram.

[image]

Is the schema legal ? What is its meaning ?

Answer (score 1):

Information flow is defined on p. 667:

> InformationFlows describe circulation of information through a system in a general manner. They do not specify the
>   nature of the information, mechanisms by which it is conveyed, sequences of exchange, or any control conditions.

Information flow is a way to model data/information flow but without details or "implementation constraints".

The source and the target are NameElement, see p. 670:

```
informationSource : NamedElement [1..*]
informationTarget : NamedElement [1..*]
```

`NamedElement` is one of the root classes of the meta-model.

It means that an information flow may be modeled between almost all UML classes.

**After what could the schema mean?**

An InformationFlow is not a transition. `State3` is never reached and has no transition: it is not involved in the state machine. If `State3` will be removed the state machine stays the same.

Even if the schema is correct, the meaning of information flows in a such context is not defined by the norm. States must be reached by `Transitions`.

If data have to be transferred from one state to another, a solution could be to create a subclass of `Event`, add properties to this subclass, and model that as instance of this subclass to trigger the transition.

Comment: To answer to a question asked by someone i know.

Comment: The shown diagram still looks pointless. There's a state hanging around which is not connected by a ControlFlow. If it were a state within, say, parallel state machine, it could make sense somehow,. But this way?

Comment: Oops. I missed your last sentence. You'd probably had put that as the fist in your answer!

Comment: @Kilian, no problem, but I take in account what you said about usage dependency: it always possible to define a sens on a schema :)

Comment: @Kilian thanks for the improvement, I will use it for others questions or answers.

Comment: @Kilian I removed the sentence "`State`s must be reached by either `InformationFlow` or `ObjectFlow` to have a meaning."  I do not understand it.

Comment: Well, my bad! Got a brain shift and landed in actions, rather than states. Of course it must read "`States` must be reached by `Transition`s".